# One way among different expressions of "subset()" function failed in R

Tags: r

I found in the Help file of `subset()` that different syntax occur for the "selection" or "inverse selection". Specifically, in "selection" example, the columns's name are surrounded by `c()`, but in "inverse selection", there is no `c()`. In addition, they both don't have quatation mark. So I tried some different syntax:

```
## For `selection` 
# standard usage in Help
subset(airquality, select = c(Temp))

# some different syntax
# (1a) add quotation mark: worked
subset(airquality, select = c("Temp"))
# (2a) remove "c()": worked
subset(airquality, select = Temp)

## For `inverse selection` 
# standard usage in Help
subset(airquality, select = -Temp)

# some different syntax
# (1b) add "c()": worked
subset(airquality, select = -c(Temp))
# (2b) add quotation mark: failed
#     Error in -c("Temp") : invalid argument to unary operator
subset(airquality, select = -c("Temp"))
```

These non-standard usage all worked, except the last example. The last example generated an error: `Error in -c("Temp") : invalid argument to unary operator`

I have two questions:

(1) Why does this error occur? Because in `(1a)` and `(2b)`, these two non-standard usage seems the same, but `(1a)` succeeded, while `(2b)` failed.

(2) Could someone tell me when should I use `c()`, or `""` in `c()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I dug into the source function of `subset`:

```
subset <- function(df, vars) {
  vars <- substitute(vars)
  var_pos <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(df)), names(df))
  pos <- eval(vars, var_pos)
  df[, pos, drop = FALSE]
}
```

The key issue here is how `pos` is evaluated inside `subset` function.

In our case, we have `df = airquality`, `vars = c(Temp)`, `vars = c("Temp")`,`vars = Temp`, `vars = -Temp`, `vars = -c(Temp)` and `vars = -c("Temp")`

Let's explicitly evaluate function `subset` line-by-line for `vars = "Temp"` and `vars = -"Temp"`:

```
vars <- substitute("Temp")
> vars
[1] "Temp"

var_pos <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(airquality)), names(airquality))
> var_pos
$Ozone
[1] 1

$Solar.R
[1] 2

$Wind
[1] 3

$Temp
[1] 4

$Month
[1] 5

$Day
[1] 6

pos <- eval(vars, var_pos)
> pos
[1] "Temp"

df <- airquality[, pos, drop = FALSE]
> head(df)
  Temp
1   67
2   72
3   74
4   62
5   56
6   66
```

This evaluated fine since there is no operation applied on `"Temp"`. However, if we try with input `-"Temp"`, we get the following:

```
vars <- substitute(-"Temp")
> vars
-"Temp"
var_pos <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(airquality)), names(airquality))
> var_pos
$Ozone
[1] 1

$Solar.R
[1] 2

$Wind
[1] 3

$Temp
[1] 4

$Month
[1] 5

$Day
[1] 6
pos <- eval(vars, var_pos)
```

> Error in -"Temp": invalid argument to unary operator

We receive this error because `eval` should be an operation with only one operand, that is it requires a single input while in this case, we basically supply two operands, i.e. mathematically speaking we do: `f:(-1) x 'Temp' -> var_pos`.

So one might ask why then input `-Temp` works.
Let's see what the output of `pos` is in that case:

```
 vars <- substitute(-Temp)
> vars
-Temp
var_pos <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(airquality)), names(airquality))
pos <- eval(vars, var_pos)
> pos
[1] -4
```

Here we have `pos` which is `-4` so we can drop *the fourth* column from our data frame.

```
df <- airquality[, pos, drop = FALSE]
> head(df)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Month Day
1    41     190  7.4     5   1
2    36     118  8.0     5   2
3    12     149 12.6     5   3
4    18     313 11.5     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9     5   6
```